# Does exists any agnostic library validation framework in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I'm looking for a validation framework for javascript similar to [backbone.validations](https://github.com/n-time/backbone.validations)

I've seen some plugin for jQuery, but I need a model validation framework not a form validation framework.

Comment: If it's on the CLIENT is needs to be server agnostic, period.

Comment: It'd be better, but not necessary. I'm afraid, that this kind of library is usually developed as a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Ext js 4.x offers a model validations.

[data.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model)